# Merging two Xcode projects... Workspaces / Schemes?

Tags: xcode

I have two projects.  One is written in Swift 3, while the other is written in Objective C.  Both compile and run fine.

I have tried to add the Objective C project into Swift by adding files to the project.  The project won't build because it can't import the bridging header.  I have spent two days on this and am certain that I am correctly specifying the location of the bridging header and header files under build settings.  I'm now looking for an alternative approach to merging these projects.

From Apple: *In addition to organizing all the files in each Xcode project, a workspace provides implicit and explicit relationships among the included projects and their targets.*

Does this mean if I add the two projects to a Workspace that I can build the two targets into one target resulting in one product?  I read something about using schemes, but the post wasn't detailed.  I'm running Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workspace is used to maintain multiple projects in single space.It wont merge two projects and create a single target/product.

Simple way to add bridging header, create a new ObjectiveC/Swift file in the project will prompt "**Would you like to configure an Objective-C bridging header?**" dialog by xcode, will automatically create the "yourprojectname-Swift.h" file for you.

Comment: ....Thanks, but I've tried that.  I'm at a total loss as to why it won't import that bridging header.  If I delete the import statement in the header the header imports fine, but then the project won't build because it can't find the Objective C files.  the file I'm pointing the import statement to certainly exists in the project.

Comment: I figured out what my issue was.  Please see the bottom of thread if interested:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246900/issue-importing-header-files?noredirect=1#comment67757359_40246900